# Compile Python module in C with -lwiringPy

Tags: python, c, module, raspberry-pi

I have written a Python module in C that uses the WiringPy library to control pins on a raspberry pi. However, after I have compiled the C module and I try to import the module in my python script I get an error message saying

```
undefined symbol: digitalWrite
```

(which is a function from WiringPy that I am using in my C file).

I compile and install my C module like this with a Python setup script.

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
setup(name='PyRFWrap', version='1.0',  \
ext_modules=[Extension('PyRFWrap', ['gpiotest.c'], extra_compile_args=['-lwiringPi'])])
```

How should I do to install and compile my C file correctly? When I compile it with GCC and run the C file independently, it works perfectly.

Comment: Need to see the makefile/build procedure

Comment: All I do to build is in the three row python script above.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use extra_linker_args instead of extra_compile_args since the flag -lwiringPi is for the linker and not the compiler.